# Sculpting Problem wont Make changes

Tags: sculpting

At the first sculpting it's working and I click apply with the changes but after clicking sculpting because I want to make some changes.

After clicking brush it doesn't change anything I don't know what is the problem right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on your model (in the *Layout* tab) and go to *Sculpt Mode*.

At first I was clicking on other object, that is why when I try to change my current model it wont work.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean, maybe this will help: you can stay in Sculpt mode and switch from an object to another: put your mouse cursor on another object and press Alt Q